# Some problems with pro-forma comments

Tags: support, bug, stackexchange

I installed [Pro-forma comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/pro-forma-comments) yesterday and it worked fine, I really like it. But today something is wrong. I can not see **auto** link near **help**. Also, when I flag question as duplicate, there does not appear comment "possible duplicate of ..." I reinstalled the script, checked if JavaScript is enabled (it was), but still have this problem. Can someone explain me what happens?

Comment: This is a known problem. Hopefully a fix will come out soon. See http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se?answertab=active#tab-top for a workaround.

Comment: @Seth, thanks for quick help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The work around suggested in the answer [here](https://stackapps.com/a/4241/17333) appears to be working for me (Thanks @Seth !).

The line you want to change in the original script (autoreviewcomments.user.js) is as follows:

```
$('#' + divid).find('.comment-help-link').parent().append(newspan);
```

From the answer provided:

> The workaround for this is to change line 683 to:
>
> ```
> setTimeout(function() {
>     $('#' + divid).find('.comment-help-link').parent().append(newspan);
> }, 10);
> ```

Personally, I would keep this as only a temporary fix, and monitor [the question](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se/4241#4241) for status updates.

Answer (score 5):

Ben Collins ♦ was making some changes to the comment system and something he did caused the userscript to stop working ([ref. 1](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1454912#1454912), [ref 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190228/did-se-change-something-that-caused-the-pro-forma-comment-script-to-stop-working#comment589333_190228)). The author of the script, Benjol, is aware of the problem and AFAIK is working on a fix.

Several ([one](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7061/44179), [two](https://stackapps.com/a/4241/14817)) workarounds have been suggested until the issue has been resolved.

Tim Stone [said he might be able to give it a look](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1456036#1456036) as well.

---

**update august 12**

The issue has been resolved in a recent update to the script.

For more information see this answer https://stackapps.com/a/4241/14817

Comment: Thanks, but I accept maggotbrain's answer, because he posted working solution. Nevertheless, I appreciate your help!